# Servicio web con PHP + nusoap

Tags: php, webservice, servidor, soap

Buenas noches,

necesito su ayuda para entender como crear un webservice haciendo uso de la "librería" **nusoap**, he visto muchas ejemplos con código, pero no explican que significa cada parámetro, por lo que si tengo que modificarlo, aunque sea lo mas mínimo, ya no me funciona.

```
    //Incluye a toolkit
require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
//Instancia al servidor
$server = new nusoap_server();

$server->configureWSDL('Prueba sobre WS', 'urn:pr');

//Parametros de entrada
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('datos_entrada',
                              'complexType',
                              'struct', 
                              'all',
                              '',
                              array('pais'=>array('name'=>'pais', 'type'=>'wsl:string'),
                                    'ciudad'=>array('name'=>'ciudad', 'type'=>'wsl:string')
                                   )
                             );

//Parametros de salida
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('datos_salida',
                              'complexType',
                              'struct', 
                              'all',
                              '',
                              array('mensaje'=>array('name'=>'mensaje', 'type'=>'wsl:string')
                                   )
                             );

//Registrar las funciones
$server->register(
                    'gettime',
                    array('datos_entrada'=>'tns:datos_entrada'),
                    array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
                    'urn:pr',
                    'urn:pr#gettime',
                    'rpc',  
                    'encoded',
                    'Return time'
                 );


//Invocar
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

//Funciones

function gettime($datos){
    return 'nublado';
}
```

Tengo algunas preguntas:

1- ¿Es obligatorio para que funcione definir los parámetros de entrada y salida? o solo se pone como información

2- ¿Que es urn? he visto que muchos ahí ponen una variable $namespace, pero ¿que es $namespace?, o sea, ¿que nombre exactamente debo poner? nombre de mi clase php, nombre de dominio, ¿o que?

3- ¿Que es "tns" y "xsd" ?

4- "complexType" y "struct" ¿pueden tomar otros valores? de ser así ¿cuando? y ¿cuales?

5- Si tengo clases en mi servidor, ¿como registro sus métodos?

Me gustaría saber por si debo recibir un parámetro o muchos, o quizás retornar una variable, un código o muchos valores, actualmente no tengo ni idea de como registrarlo.

Hace varias horas estoy intentado, pero no logro avanzar, me gustaría que alguien me lo explique, y si pueden darme código de ejemplo seria genial, con variables donde se tenga que modificar el valor.

Ultima pregunta ¿que hace en  linea?

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

Comment: Las preguntas hay que hacerlas de a una ( o en su defecto acotarlas). La mayoria de esas preguntas tienen solucion simple, XSD por ejemplo es un tipo de archivo de definicion de un xml. Ahora si esta libreria te esta trayendo problemas y tiene poca documentacion, no seria mejor idea buscar otra?